# GRUB default boot editing

Tags: boot, grub

I have a box with Ubuntu, FreeBSD and Win32. The default boot preference is Ubuntu.

How can I change that option to be FreeBSD(or Win)? Can the boot selection time frame (currently of 10 seconds) be modified as well?

Comment: Think you're on the wrong subsite :) Nevertheless; are you using GRUB?

Comment: I haven't used it before. I only want to change the default boot selection. If the question is not in the right section please remove it.

Comment: Well, if you are seeing some kind of boot menu right now, you have a bootloader already installed and you are using it :) best chance is this is GRUB. If you don't have any experience with using VI or editing text configuration files, then I wouldn't recommend trying to change values in it. There are some GUI tools around to change the GRUB configuration from your desktop. Like this one; http://www.unixmen.com/grub-customizer-2-5-5-is-available-customize-grubburg-from-a-gui-interface/

Comment: Using vi is not the issue. It's just that I am not very familiar with GRUB. Thanks for the link.

Comment: In case you are familiar with all of that, you should check out `/etc/default/grub` and run `update-grub` afterwards. The config file should be self explanatory